# custom oAuth2 token after a sam2 assertion check

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I need to release, using wso2 is, a custom oAuth2 token after a check on saml2 assertion as input. 
How is it possibile customized the oAuth2 token ?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve OAuth access token for SAML2 assertion. As WSO2 Identity Server 4.5.0 supports saml2 bearer assertion grant type. You can find the [doc](http://soasecurity.org/2014/10/31/saml2-bearer-assertion-profile-for-oauth-2-0/). You can modify the returning OAuth2 access token by adding custom implementation. There is an [interface](http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/components/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth/4.2.0/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/oauth2/token/handlers/grant/AuthorizationGrantHandler.java) that you can implement this. Here you have a method called "issue".  Actually you may can implement the Abstract class of this. However i have not done this.. Just for information.

Comment: Thanks for answer, the link to documentation it is very useful, for the custom token it is not clear how to implement the abstract class and I didn't find any help or example for tho, the question is do I need to implement a new application similar to oauth2 war application?

Comment: I am not exactly sure about.. However this is not much extensible. but in "org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth" package there are some implementation. You can look for them. One this is done, You can replace the jar file. which is already there.

Comment: I didn't find any source code related to the package "org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth" do you know how can we build my customisation? thanks a lot

Comment: i meant here http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/components/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth/4.2.0/

Comment: Ok, I found all source-code and the methods issueAccessToken on OAuth2Service and issue on AccessTokenIssuer classes maybe are very useful for my scope. thanks a lot. Just another questions, in order to have everything more clear, for building the package I have some problem with maven 3.1.1, maybe due a some dependencies, so where can I find a complete guide for building only this package? at the end of build phase I need to configure this package as plying. Where can I find details about this kind of configuration?

Comment: Ehi Asela, in the source code I didn't find the following packages org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.common and org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.common.exception necessary during the startup of server

Comment: Basically you may need to modify the source in the "AbstractAuthorizationGrantHandler" class. There,  you can find the code that generate the access token  "accessToken = oauthIssuerImpl.accessToken();"  ...  However AFAIK, it is not possibly to plug an another implementation. Therefore you may need to modify the code to create access token with custom values. But there would be an extension in future release.

Comment: There can be dependency for oauth.common. You can find it http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/components/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.common/4.2.0/