# Supporting Custom Access Token Types in API Manager

Tags: wso2

We currently use a proprietary access token format similar to, but predating, JWT.  It generated by our API authentication system.  How would we go about developing an APIM plugin that can validate the token and update the message context with data extracted from it?

I think what I'm asking is, how do we support additional authentication mechanisms?

Answer (score 0):

I guess,  you need to return customized access token and also customize the authentication.  Basically  you need to add customized OAuth grant type..

It is difficult to customized access token with WSO2IS 460 (or APIM 150) and older releases. Because you may need to implement new authorization grant type handler for this. Actually you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20374120/custom-oauth2-token-after-a-sam2-assertion-check) SO question. WSO2IS plans to add this in to a next release,  you can see the mailing list discussion on from [here](http://osdir.com/ml/carbon-wso2-architecture/2013-12/msg00144.html).